# What happens if 2 processor try to access the same memory in one clock cycle?

Tags: multi-tasking, assembly

Assume a parralled adder program:

```
CPU0:
ADD sum,eax;or
LOCK ADD sum,eax

CPU1:
ADD sum,eax;or
LOCK ADD sum,eax
```

If these 2 instructions are issued in the same clock cycle, and reach memory control unit/cache control module, how does it decide which one will be served first?  If not using lock, it seems that `ADD` requires read&write, and the memory might be modified in between the latency of read&write.

If lock is asserted, will the other processor have to wait until the first one get served? And is this kind of wait similar like a cache miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn’t decide which one is first, it decides that *one* goes first and *the other* goes second.

It’s tricky, but you can and must build hardware that handles the case of two lock requests at the same time. A simple method: If you have four cores, check whether core 0 has a lock request in cycle n, check core 1 in cycle n+1, check core 2 in cycle n+2, core 3 in cycle n+3, and back to core 0 in cycle n+4. So to that hardware, there can’t be “simultaneous” lock requests.

And obviously when the first CPU is given access, the second one has to wait. That’s the whole point. (Obviously the processor can try to do other work while waiting for the lock).